# Getting the width and height of every cell in a selected range

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

To give you a bit of context, I am trying to retrieve the `width` and `height` properties of each cell in a selected range. For this I am using the Office Javascript API and so far the only way I can think of is by looping over every cell in the selected range and retrieving said properties for each.

Assuming `selectedRange` is the user's selection and the appropriate properties have been loaded beforehand, this is what I would have:

```
    for (let r = 0; r < selectedRange.rowCount; r++) {
      console.log(selectedRange.getRow(r).height);
      for (let c = 0; c < selectedRange.columnCount; c++) {
        console.log(selectedRange.getColumn(c).width);
      }
    }
```

The problem however, is that the `width` and `height` properties for each column and row are not loaded and correct me if I'm wrong, but they would have to be loaded inside the loop for each column and row. That would in turn mean calling `context.sync()` quite a few times inside the loop which is a very bad idea according to the official documentation.

So, is there another way of doing this, which wouldn't involve calling `context.sync()` so often?

I am still quite new to Office Js, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a way to do this without calling context.sync inside a loop. You need to use the split loop pattern. For details and examples, see [Avoid using the context.sync method in loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern?view=word-js-preview) and the Stack answers that it links to.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much @rick-kirkham !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly you would like to access each cell's hight and width.
So you may try `range.format.rowHight` and `range.format.columnWidth`

Therefore you could use `range.getCellProperties` which will return a 2d array for you with width and hight information for each cell of this range.

Here is the document for `range.getCellProperties`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#getcellproperties-cellpropertiesloadoptions-

Comment: There isn't any columnWidth or rowHeight property in the 2d array returned by range.getCellProperties() though.

Comment: I think you probably meant selectedRange.getColumnProperties({ format: { columnWidth: true } }) which would allow me to only call context.sync() once and then I can loop over the array returned by getColumnProperties(). Thank you for your help.

Comment: @iHaveCodingIssues is getColumnProperties() working for you? I can see that if column width is not the same for all cells, this property will be set to Null https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-getcolumnproperties-member(1)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to keep all the ranges (cell) and load them all in the same context.sync(), then output the height and Width after that. You must call range.untrack to save memory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#untrack--

Besides, Your code above can do some optimization, It don't need to be n*m, n+m is enough.

let selectedRange = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

```
selectedRange.load("rowCount,columnCount");
await context.sync();

for (let r = 0; r < selectedRange.rowCount; r++) {
  let row = selectedRange.getRow(r);
  row.load("height");
  await context.sync();

  console.log(row.height);
  }

for (let c = 0; c < selectedRange.columnCount; c++) {
  let column = selectedRange.getColumn(c);
  column.load("width");
  await context.sync();
  console.log(column.width);
}
```

Comment: @MandyMSFT. Thanks for the answer, but even n+m isn't needed. It can be just 1 or 2. See my answer.

Comment: @RickKirkham thanks for the official document support. Split loop is actually the option i gave in above comment by saying "One possible way is to keep all the ranges (cell) and load them all in the same context.sync(), then output the height and Width after that. You must call range.untrack to save memory." :)

Comment: @MandyMSFT OK. But then why even mention the less optimal n+m pattern as an "optimization"?

Comment: @RickKirkham I am new contributor to stackoverflow, not quite sure the reply rule. Does that mean we should only focus on one answer in each reply ?  I  am just thinking providing the optimization may help have a better code in future.

Comment: @MandyMSFT You're doing fine and I'm grateful for your involvement. My concern is that no one should ever use your n+m optimization, because it has a `context.sync` inside a loop, so there will *always* be a better optimization as described in article I linked to in my answer, and as indicated in the very first part of your answer.